# When to use before or beforehand?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, synonyms, adverbs, past-tense

Both beforehand and before are adverb and both mean the same. (See Reference, below). Then what is the difference between them? Can they be used interchangeably?

### Are these sentence correct (and can I swap before with beforehand)?

A: Have you had an avocado before?

B: No, I never had an avocado before.

---

A: Before I say anything, I must say that you are an honest person.

---

A: I had missed my bus before I decided to take a taxi.

### Reference

- [beforehand - Dictionary Definition : Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/beforehand?family=Beforehand)
- [before - Dictionary Definition : Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/before)

Comment: But you don't say why the different definitions given fail to address your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Before* and *beforehand* don't mean exactly the same. *Beforehand* would not be appropriate in any of your example sentences, as is has the sense of doing something in preparation for a later event ('in anticipation', as the definition says).

> I missed the bus because I had not checked the timetable beforehand.
>
> When I interviewed [the celebrity] I had read a lot of information about him beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentences are correct, and you cannot substitute beforehand in any of them.

Beforehand is used in, for example

```
 I am going to the supermarket, but I am going to get petrol beforehand.
```

It usually refers back to something previously mentioned, and means before that. The previous mention may be only implied eg

```
 You will need to book beforehand
```

referring to the event, accomodation, etc that needs to be booked.